# Qt and PyQt hybrid application

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt, boost-python

I have a C++ application using Qt for the UI and I'm currently implementing python bindings so that the application is more scriptable for its users. I also want people to be able to write their own custom widgets in PyQt, and have access to the core functionality via the boost::python bindings.

To do this, I want to allow signals to be connected from either the PyQt widgets to the Qt widgets, or vice versa, so I need to parent the PyQt to the Qt in some way. I've heard that it can be done, but after a bit of searching can't find any examples.

Does anyone have any references for this kind of thing?

Comment: The answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940686/using-custom-qt-subclasses-in-python might be of interest. I guess you would need to learn how `SIP` works and extend PyQt. I guess this is not trivial.

Comment: Instead of closing this question because it's off-topic it would have actually been sufficient to just remove or alter the last sentence into something less off-topic. Geesh...

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a tutorial that discusses it](http://lynxline.com/qt-python-superhybrids/). Another can be found [here](http://acaciaecho.wordpress.com/2011/08/15/hybridqtwithpyqt/). Also, I am guessing that most of it can be crossed over via the numerous ways to interface python and C/C++ files.