# Wrapping C++ Qt widget for using in Python with PySide

Tags: python, qt, pyside, swig

What is the best approach for wrapping a custom C++ library with custom Qt display widgets in Python for using in a PySide based QApplication?  Does the C++ library need special treatment for wrapping with SWIG?  Will wrapped Qt widgets integrate properly with PySide?

I would appreciate any comments on the appropriate nomenclature needed to refine my unsuccessful searches on this subject.

Comment: Are you writing/controlling the C++ code?

Comment: Yes, it is an in-house C++ project with a Qt interface.  I want to reimplement the main application in Python but use the existing custom C++ Qt widgets and classes as is.

Comment: Maybe this will be of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940686/using-custom-qt-subclasses-in-python

Answer (score 2):

The Shiboken bindings tool used to generate the PySide bindings for Qt turns out to be the right tool for the job.

The basic procedure for generating the bindings for a custom C++ library is outlined here:
http://lynxline.com/superhybrids-part-2-now-qt-pyside/